# How to get Input field type as props in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

how I get input field type as the props in react typescript I tried to send type as the string but it gives this error

**

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 2, '(props: InputProps | Readonly): Input', gave the following error.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"number" | "button" | "select" | "textarea" | "time" | "image" | "text" | "hidden" | "color" | "email" | "file" | "radio" | "checkbox" | "reset" | "submit" | "date" | "datetime-local" | ... 8 more ... | undefined'.
> Overload 2 of 2, '(props: InputProps, context: any): Input', gave the following error.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"number" | "button" | "select" | "textarea" | "time" | "image" | "text" | "hidden" | "color" | "email" | "file" | "radio" | "checkbox" | "reset" | "submit" | "date" | "datetime-local" | ... 8 more ... | undefined'.  TS2769

**

here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';


interface IconInputProps {
    name: string,
    label: string,
    placeholder: string,
    required: boolean,
    errorMessage: string,
    autoFocus: boolean,
    type: string
    icon: string

}

class IconInput extends React.Component<IconInputProps> {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Input
                    name={this.props.name}
                    lable={this.props.label}
                    type={this.props.type}
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default IconInput;
```

Comment: Can you provide the usage of this component?

Comment: `input` (ordinary HTML element) requires type as a string (I checked on codesandbox and my local), but `Input` (the one from 'reactstrap' you're using is requiring a more concrete type).

Comment: I guess, you need to declare constructor also as mentioned in https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could explicitly declare the type as:

```
import React, { ComponentProps } from 'react';
import { Input } from 'reactstrap';

interface IconInputProps {
    type: ComponentProps<typeof Input>['type'];
    // ...
}
```

This *passes through* the type declaration of a specific component prop and works even if that type is not exported by the given lib/component.

---

Though there are a few caveats:

> does not work with statically declared default props and generic props

Source: https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#reactcomponentpropstypeof-xxx

Comment: Looks great. I guess it seems more readable than mine

Answer (score 1):

`type: string` should be replace by `type: InputType`

And don't forget to import this `import { InputType } from "reactstrap/lib/Input.d";`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extend the `InputProps` which you should import from `@types/reactstrap` ( i guess it has types )

In your interface just add the props that are not in `InputProps`. So you can remove `type, name`  and so on. So your code will look something like

```
interface IIconInputProps extends InputProps {
    label: string,
    errorMessage: string,
    icon: string
}
```

Also I would suggest to start the `interface` names with `I` so you know it's an interface.